# duplicate symbols for architecture while converting an iphone app to universal app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5, ios-simulator

While converting an iphone app to ipad app I have created a new file and named it ipad as prefix, This is my AppDelegate.m includes. All the code are the same but the class name are different.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import "ipadSearchViewController.h"
#import "ipadLoginViewController.h"
#import "ipadSettingsViewController.h"
```

While trying to build the project this is the error:

```
ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

but there is no duplicate variable, I am using different variable name for iphone and ipod.

Comment: have you renamed the class as well? or just the file? however, the good practice is to make a different `.xib` file and using the same class for the `...~iphone.xib` and `...~ipad.xib`. inside the code you can separate the parts relevant between the devices using the `if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { ...iPad parts... } else { ...iPhone parts... }` statement and you don't need to duplicate the common parts.

Comment: ya holex, i have renamed the class name also. But facing the same problem

Comment: Do you have any static vars in this file?  Is everything @property definitions?  Also, did you do a Clean in the project?

Comment: @Shyantanu, then, post your code, please, we will never find out what symbol(s) duplicated, the generic message does not say anything.

Comment: @holex how can i send u the code?

Comment: @Shyantanu, e.g. via **[bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org)**...?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer with so little code... I would recommend going in build phases and manually ensuring that each resources only appears once under "Copy Bundle Ressource"